# Removing rows with non-unique values based on a second variable in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set with time stamps and location names (radio-tracking data). I want to remove all instances where there are two different locations at the same time stamp (detected by two different receivers at the same time).

Example data set:

```
ts<-c("2014-08-07 20:12", "2014-08-07 20:12",  "2014-08-07 20:13","2014-08-07 20:13","2014-08-07 20:14", "2014-08-07 20:14")
site<-c(a,a,a,b,c,c)
df<-data.frame(cbind(ts,site))
df
                ts site
1 2014-08-07 20:12    a
2 2014-08-07 20:12    a
3 2014-08-07 20:13    a
4 2014-08-07 20:13    b
5 2014-08-07 20:14    c
6 2014-08-07 20:14    c
```

So I want to remove lines 3&4, but keep 1,2,5 and 6.

I have looked at different applications of *duplicated*, *distinct* and *unique*, but can't figure out how to base it on another column (in this case timestamp).

Any and all help appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr` you can determine the number of `n_distinct` sites for each time stamp, then filter those that are not equal to 2 (you could also just filter if equal to 1 as well).

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ts) %>%
  mutate(num_loc = n_distinct(site)) %>%
  filter(num_loc!=2)
```

Similar to @wusel's answer, you could just filter as:

```
filter(n_distinct(site) == 1)
```

and then leave out `mutate`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my approach with `dplyr`

```
df %>% 
  # consider each time stamp seperately
  group_by(ts) %>% 
  # keep only observations which have one unique `site` value
  filter(length(unique(site)) == 1)
```